# Conversion of number into another number with different base using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am converting a number into another number with different base using recursion but here is an problem in my code. My code is not according to my requirement. Please check and tell me where is the problem?
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int baseFunction(int, int);
int main()
{
    int number,base;
    cout<<"Enter number: ";
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"Enter base: ";
    cin>>base;
    cout<<"OutPut "<<number<<" is ";
    baseFunction(number,base);
    cout<<" in base "<<base<<endl;

}
int baseFunction(int n,int b)
{
    if(n==1)
        return n;
    else
    {
        baseFunction(n/b,b);
        cout<<n%b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Numbers don't have "bases". What's the base of the number of fingers on your hand?

Comment: Base can be 3, 8 , 16 etc.

Comment: Numbers don't have bases; text representations of numbers do.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have thought in the correct direction but you have made a small mistake in your logic.

```
if(n==1)
    return n;
else
{
    baseFunction(n/b,b);
    cout<<n%b;
}
```

This will only return when n=1, which is not correct if you want to use the code for converting it to other bases.
For example, if you want to convert 10 to octal i.e. base=8, then the calculation of n/b will never give you 1. It will give n=2 in the first time and 0 for the next recursion. So, that will not work for your code.

Consider the code below:

```
    if(n>0)
    {
        baseFunction(n/b,b);
        cout<<n%b;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
```

Now this will work since as soon as the value of n becomes less than 0, the recursion will terminate and will give you the correct result.

This code will certainly not work for conversion to hexadecimal(base=16). You could try adding some more lines of code in this to make it work for hexadecimal conversion as well.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

```
cout<<"Enter number: ";
//enters NUMBER
cin>>number;
cout<<"Enter base: ";
//enters BASE
cin>>base;
cout<<"OutPut "<<number<<" is ";
//function, that returns int, returns it to nothing, so nothing changes
baseFunction(number,base);
//BASE unaffected, since function did nothing
cout<<" in base "<<base<<endl;
```

So, it won't work. Even if you assigned returned value, function calculations are wrong. So, you have to try harder. You should search for some number base-system conversions (possibly here, on stack).

EDIT:
Also, you should output new number, not base. I assume your initial base is 10, and final number should be of new base.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please can you give me the correct code for this program?